# From VBA (Excel) how do I click this button in an HTML / Javascript page?

Tags: html, vba

I've been going round this one for ages. A lot of the suggestions on here seem close but I can't get them working.

I can open the page, log-in, fill in the various boxes (this is all part of a filtering process)

I then just need to click the 'Go' button to start the search.

I've tried variations of 'Focus' and 'Click' etc

I think the issue is actually getting the right element to focus on and be clicked.

The HTML code for the button that needs to be pressed is

```
<td class="XUIPromptEntry"><span class="minibuttonOn"><a href="javascript:void(null)" onclick="javascript:GFPDoFilters('d:dashboard~p:nsv29jv8c3s9l61e~s:o426k5n3d5ajovme~g:49ftldfknmmr1fg5',document.getElementById('saw_6428_5'),true);return false;">Go</a></span><div id="d:dashboard~p:nsv29jv8c3s9l61e~s:o426k5n3d5ajovme~g:49ftldfknmmr1fg5Scope" value="page"/></td>
```

Can I get get a hint at what code I should use to click it.

Please help! I have to log in every Saturday and Sunday to run this report through Excel and I want my weekends back!

As requested below, here's the code I've tried so far (which has worked in other macros)

```
                Set htmlDoc = .document
            Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
            Do While htmlDoc.READYSTATE <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
                For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
                    If Trim(htmlInput.Type) = "submit" Then
                        htmlInput.Click
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next htmlInput
            End With
```

I've also tried a few other approaches including...

```
    Set link = Nothing
i = 0
While i < htmlDoc.Links.Length And link Is Nothing
    If htmlDoc.Links(i).innerText = "Go" Then Set link = htmlDoc.Links(i)
    i = i + 1
Wend
If Not link Is Nothing Then
    link.Focus
    link.Click
End If
```

But still no joy (The link.focus doesn't work because it says its invisible)

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to find the element? Maybe a little more for context?  It's hard to say what you need to change if it's not clear what you're already doing.

Comment: Call `document.GetElementsByTagName("a")` - loop through the returned collection and look for the one with innerText = "Go"

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> **SOLVED!!!**
>
> I used 'Innertext' to get it - the problem I had was once it found one and tried clicking it, it exited the loop. But it appeared 3 times so by removing the 'exit for' it found the one that actually worked.